# How do I make Sphinx stop ignoring spaces?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I'm using Sphynx and ThinkingSphynx in my Rails project. Is there any way I can make Sphynx stop ignoring spaces so that "Foo " key would find me "Foo Bar" and wouldn't find me, for example,  "foo@bar.com"  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added blend_chars option to indice and everything started working as needed:

```
set_property :blend_chars => 'U+20, @, .'
```

U+20 is actually a space.

Answer (score 0):

Sphinx is actually treating `@` as a non-indexed character, same as `.`, so they become word separators. Thus, "foo@bar.com" is actually indexed as "foo bar com".

If you want "foo@bar.com" to be kept exactly as it is, then you should add `@` and `.` to your charset_table value in `config/thinking_sphinx.yml` for each environment. My example here is the default set, plus the unicode values for those two characters at the end (40 is @, AD is .).

```
development:
  charset_table: 0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, a..z, U+410..U+42F->U+430..U+44F, U+430..U+44F, U+401->U+451, U+451, U+0040, U+00AD
```

An alternative is to add those characters to the ignore_chars option instead. This way, they're *deleted* in the indexed data, so "foo@bar.com" becomes "foobarcom":

```
development:
  ignore_chars: U+0040, U+00AD
```

Keep in mind that both of these settings will impact those characters *everywhere* in your indexed data, not just in email addresses (and no, you can't set them on a per-field basis).